# JBoss EAP 7.0 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=3 poolCount = 20 WARN

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, redhat

I have a `SpringBoot 2.2.6` Web Application and I want to run it under `JBoss EAP 7`.

I manage to start the server but from the log I can see many warning about several classes. These warnings are all simiral to the follow one:

```
WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0003: Could not index class module-info.class at /C:/server/jboss-eap-7.0/bin/content/TEST-EAR.ear/WEB-TEST.war/WEB-INF/lib/lombok-1.18.12.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=3 poolCount = 44
```

The classes involved are:

```
classmate-1.5.1.jar
jackson-annotations-2.10.3.jar
jackson-core-2.10.3.jar
jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar
jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.3.jar
jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.10.3.jar
jackson-module-parameter-names-2.10.3.jar
lombok-1.18.12.jar
```

Except for lombok, the other libraries come with `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency. Googlin around I read that problem is the libraries version.. but I hope there's another way to solve this WARN (is not a proper issue because the server starts) because exclude all these libraries from spring artifact and then re-import another version of them seems really an overkill to me..

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Googling around I have read many posts on this problem and various solution but noone works.

Finally I found a solution officially supported by *redhat*.

*This is a warning message, it occured because of jandex supports Java9 is to simply ignore module-info.class files in dependent archives. To avoid this warning messages, replace jandex jar present in*

```
JBOSS_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\jandex\main\jandex-2.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar
```

*with* `jandex-2.0.5.Final-redhat-1` *and the respective* `module.xml`.

You can found `jandex-2.0.5.Final-redhat-1` on [maven repos](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jandex/2.0.5.Final-redhat-1).

The link at the official issue is [this](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBEAP-15715).

Hope helps.