# Need Help Deploying Vaadin 14 app to JBoss EAP 7.1 on Java 8

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jboss, vaadin

I'm attempting without success to deploy a basic Spring Boot/Vaadin 14 Greeter application to JBoss 7.1 under Java 8.

Steps to recreate.

Clone [this branch](https://github.com/NCIDevRonR/vaadin-issues/tree/deploy-to-jboss-71-fails) of my GitHub repo locally.

Optionally, skip next step to use my included war file.

Navigate to vdn-hiya project’s folder, and type “mvn clean package -Pproduction” to build war file.

Observe war file successfully built in project’s “target” folder.

Run “standalone.bat” in JBoss bin folder to start Jboss EAP 7.1.

Open JBoss Admin Console.  Mine is at localhost:9990/console/App.html#home

Open Deployments tab

Click “Add”

Click “Next”

Click “Choose File”

Select vdn-hiya.war file from project’s target folder, and click “Open”.

Click “Next”

Leave “Enable selected, and click “Finish”.

Observe errors in deploy dialog, and in JBoss console output, which begin with several "Unknown tag!" errors.  Does any of this seem familiar?

Below is the first error I'm seeing when deploying to my unaltered Jboss instance.  See both complete stack traces, including the one occurring in my JBoss instance altered as recommended in other Q&A's in the [aforementioned repo](https://github.com/NCIDevRonR/vaadin-issues/tree/deploy-to-jboss-71-fails).

11:40:43,180 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."vdn-hiya.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."vdn-hiya.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1978)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Comment: Those are `WARN` tagged and there are multiple. So we can assume, that this is not a fatal error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JBoss EAP 7.0 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=3 poolCount = 20 WARN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790738/jboss-eap-7-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unknown-tag-pos-3-poolcount-20)

Comment: @cfrick  After the WARN messages come the ERROR messages, starting with:  11:07:49,137 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."vdn-hiya.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."vdn-hiya.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service

Comment: @ollitietavainen I have a second JBoss instance setup with your fix.  I get these of errors on that instance:  11:10:15,847 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."vdn-hiya.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."vdn-hiya.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service

Comment: Please edit the question - comments are not suitable to improve it

Comment: Is this all? Not stacktrace?

Comment: I have just now uploaded both referenced stack traces, in their entirety, into the aforementioned repo.  See link above.

Comment: I'd hope there would be some more log explaining the root cause of _why_ the service failed to start

Comment: Why are you using this outdated technology?

Comment: @ollitietavainen, if you know a way I can expose more log output to get at the root cause, I'm all ears.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, our client is the government, and our application is a relatively small tool that's part of a larger system maintained by another team, and as such we piggyback on their runtime environment.